# Can't use eslint loader in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I'm getting familiar to webpack. And it went well before I tried to add eslint loader to my webpack config. I got

> ERROR in ./src/index.js
>   Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'eslint'

in my console when run webpack command. Here's my webpack.config.js

```
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [
        'eslint-loader', {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
      }, {
          loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
      }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
      }],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "animatio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server",
    "deploy": "git push evennode master"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

And finally my src/index.js:

```
import styles from './main.scss';

console.log('Something.')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty obvious.
I haven't installed eslint itself (loader only). After installation and .eslint file creation it works OK.

Answer (score -1):

Building an Environment: Automatic Linting with Webpack
https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/react/react-fundamentals/building-an-environment-automatic-linting-with-webpack

Comment: the link is broken